# Bypassing security box when reading outlook messages using python win32com.client dispatch or dispatchex

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, win32com

I'm reading messages from an outlook inbox and am opening outlook with the following command in python 3.6:

```
outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

The problem that I'm having is that whenever I do this, the user then has to manually got to their outlook and allow an outside program to read messages. I'm wondering if there's a way to get around this problem.

It seems that using:

```
outlook=win32com.client.DispatchEx("Outlook.Application")
```

could help by opening outlook in a different account that doesn't require the user's allowance, but I can't find documentation on what that command actually does.

After opening outlook I want to be able to use it in the following way:

```
# Open a msg file using outlook.
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(abs_path)

# Extract text from the message.
all_text = "Subject:\n" + msg.Subject + "\n\n"
all_text += "Body:\n" + msg.Body
```

How should I try to open outlook/ rewrite my code in a way that doesn't require the user to manually allow my program access? Also, side note, is there a good way to prevent the processes I do in outlook from opening any windows on my computer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using pywin32, what is the difference between Dispatch and DispatchEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648933/using-pywin32-what-is-the-difference-between-dispatch-and-dispatchex)

Comment: That thread is only about using dispatch for excel, and the answer's are pretty split between the two methods. Also the problem with the user needing to manually allow reading is specific to outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, installing an up-to-date antivirus app would get rid of the security prompts. If you cannot control the environment, there are ways to work around them programmatically. See http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for more details.