# Accessing a specific instance of Enterprise Architect via COM from Python

Tags: python, scripting, com, win32com, enterprise-architect

A running instance of EA can be accessed from a Python script with something like:

```
from win32com import client
eaApp = client.GetActiveObject("EA.App")
eaRepo = eaApp.Repository
```

However, this seems to always returns the COM object of the instance first started.

Let's say we have a script that needs to starts a new instance of EA. It does so by calling `os.startfile(eapxFile)` with `eapxFile` being the path to an empty EA file. Then it should import some XMI file, for which it needs access to the COM object.

At the same time, a couple of other (older) instances of EA are open. How can the COM object of the new instance of EA be retrieved?

***Note:**
An alternative way of starting a new instance of EA, if immediate access to its COM object is possible, would of course be feasible as well. Maybe even  using the COM interface directly. Most importantly, other running instances of EA can not be used.*

Comment: I don't get it. If you start a new instance, then you already have the COM object don't you? There would not be a need to get a specific running instance.

Comment: @GeertBellekens He wants to pick a certain instance from multiple running ones I guess. Personally I only deal with a single EA instance in all cases. Simple requirement for my scripts.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I started the new instance by calling the EA executable.

Comment: Basically if there is a way to get a COM object for a newly created instance of EA, that would be awesome. I tried using `DispatchEx` to get a 'new' COM object as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648933/using-pywin32-what-is-the-difference-between-dispatch-and-dispatchex but that just seems to freeze my script.

Comment: Seems you are right and Dispatch also accesses the current runnng instance.

Comment: DispatchEx has a different signature: `def DispatchEx(clsid, machine=None, userName=None, resultCLSID=None, typeinfo=None, UnicodeToString=None, clsctx=None) ` rather than `def Dispatch(dispatch, userName=None, resultCLSID=None, typeinfo=None, UnicodeToString=None, clsctx=21) `

Comment: A bit of googling was very unpromising. Even the author of win32api has no example of that Ex. I'm no windoze specialist. Would well be interested in an answer.

Comment: Just an abstruse idea: if you fliddle with the registry and place EAx.app as a doppleganger you might trick windoze.

Comment: this answers seems to indicate how to create a new instance of a com object in python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36711595/2018133

Comment: @GeertBellekens On trying the suggested code, I saw it manages to return a 'different' COM object - that is, comparing `app1 == app2` returns `False` - but they both still seem to be pointing to the same EA instance.

Comment: there is no defined way to get a specific instance of an out-of-process COM object[i.e. apps like Excel, word, ], unless that application specifically provides any way to enumerate all its running instances.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran: You mean by adding the EA instance to the Running Object Table? Perhaps EA does this then you could get your hands on it.

Comment: The application(in this case EA) has to register with ROT or provide any other ways to enumerate all its active running instances. I am not sure if EA does it though.

Comment: @Benjamin4991 have you tried using the psutil python module, it provides ways to enumerate all the runninc processess. You can iterate and get the active instances of EA and determine somehow[using process.create_time() !] the one launched by your script. Refer this documentation for (psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#processes).

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I can confirm that "monikers" of different instances of EA are visible in the Running Object Table. Through `moniker.GetDisplayName(context, moniker)` a display name like `!Sparx.EA.App:14432` is returned. Starting with a moniker object, or to be precise, a `PyIMoniker` object like that, how do I get to the COM object so that I can access the EA API?

Comment: When you iterate the monikers by calling pythoncom.GetRunningObjectTable, the PyIMoniker exposes a BindToObject method, that may need to be used, or if somehow you get the `Dispatch` interface, then you could call methods exposed by EA app. see this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUthExQRzOM), it may give some clues.

Comment: As the EA guru @GeertBellekens asks above, can you post your script. if your script is creating new instance of EA, it does not matter there were other running EA instances, your script would have got the pointer to the instance that was fired by your script, so you could get its Repository and do your automation, is it not?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran That's exactly what _not_ happens. Dispatch will eventually create an instance if there is none. But else it will return the already running one and _not_ create a new one.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Just edited the question, hopefully clarifiying how the instance of EA was launched that I am trying to access through COM.

Comment: As an alternative you could start by accessing the (new or existing) EA instance using Dispatch, and then use Repository.OpenFile(eapxfile) to open the new model. Downside to this approach is that it will highjack your existing EA instance if you have one running.

Comment: Yes @GeertBellekens, that is unfortunately exactly what I need to avoid. Other instances of EA must be left untouched.

Comment: That's too bad. I'm pretty sure there must be a solution. I can do it in VBScript using `CreateObject("EA.Repository")` so there must be an equivalent to do the same in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBScript you can create an `EA.Repository` object in a brand new EA instance using

```
dim repository
set repository = CreateObject("EA.Repository")
```

The Python equivalent seems to be

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
repository = CreateObject("EA.Repository")
```

then open a model using

```
repository.OpenFile(myEapFile)
```

close the model using

```
repository.CloseFile()
```

followed by

```
repository.Exit()
```

to make sure the instance of the ea.exe process is closed.

Comment: Cool stuff, I didn't know about the comtypes library. On playing around with that in the Python Console, I see `CreateObject` reliably gives me _one_ new EA instance no matter how many other _manually started_ EAs are already running. But once I start one EA instance with `CreateObject`, if I try to do it again I either get the same old one I started previously or the console/script simply freezes. Guessing this might be an issue on EAs side. Unfortunately, starting up several instances of EA by script is a use case for us...

Comment: I added another question to ask specifically for how to start a new EA through COM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70068010/get-a-com-object-of-a-new-enterprise-architect-instance-in-python - can't really accept this as an answer for the question I posed. Feel free to put the answer there as well.

Comment: Verified that this is working :-)

Comment: @Benjamin4991 this new question is just the same as this one and Geert answered it well!

Comment: Actually, you're right.